# how to add header text or License header into already existing java classes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i am able to add the header text for newly created classes but for existing classes i'm not getting , how to do  please anybody help me to get rid of this.

```
/**
 *  Copyright © 2018  XYZ,
 *  All rights reserved.
 *  some XYZ PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. 
 */
 package org.xxx.admin.controller.alerts;

/**
 * @author Harisha N
 */
public class Qwerty{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-copyright-generator

regards,